# Setting a New Score using willSet

Tags: swift, swift2, swift3

So I am learning swift2 and I am using a friends project. He has a counter for the game but I want to create a label when the user dies. I tried setting the score label to (score) but the code sets the score to 0 and counts without chance `score`. I dont know how to make score update. This is the code

```
var score:Int = 0 {
    willSet {
        let scoreBand = childNodeWithName(StickHeroGameSceneChildName.ScoreName.rawValue) as? SKLabelNode
        scoreBand?.text = "\(newValue)"
        scoreBand?.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.scaleTo(1.5, duration: 0.1), SKAction.scaleTo(1, duration: 0.1)]))

        if (newValue == 1) {
            let tip = childNodeWithName(StickHeroGameSceneChildName.TipName.rawValue) as? SKLabelNode
            tip?.runAction(SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0, duration: 0.4))
        }
    }
}

    let scoreLbl = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "AmericanTypewriter")
    scoreLbl.position = CGPointMake(0, 200)

    scoreLbl.text = "\(newValue)" // , this throws error, tried score but it = 0

    node.addChild(scoreLbl)
```

Comment: @EricAya, I tried doing that but it always 0... Why is that?

Comment: It is 'always 0' because `willSet` runs before `score` is set and thus `score` starts with its default of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `didSet` so the your code actually sees the updated value of `score`.  As such:

```
class Foo {
  var score:Int = 0 {
    didSet {
      let scoreBand = childNodeWithName(
        StickHeroGameSceneChildName.ScoreName.rawValue) as? SKLabelNode
      scoreBand?.text = "\(score)"
      scoreBand?.runAction(
        SKAction.sequence([SKAction.scaleTo(1.5, duration: 0.1),
                           SKAction.scaleTo(1  , duration: 0.1)]))

      if (score == 1) {
        let tip = childNodeWithName(
          StickHeroGameSceneChildName.TipName.rawValue) as? SKLabelNode
        tip?.runAction(SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0, duration: 0.4))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, note that `scoreBand` and `tip` are variables bound only in the context of `didSet` so they won't be accessible.  Thus your changes to the 'child nodes' are only visible if the returned SKLabelNode is mutable (supposedly it is).